# WordPress won't save page/post with more than 332 words

Tags: errors

People!

I've been having an issue with a site and can't seem to find a solution. If a post or page has more than 332 words, it won't save.

If the post is new, no content will be saved at all.

If the post already has (let's say) 100 words, going over the 332 word mark will result in not saving any changes.

I know that this is not a plug-in, theme, core conflict. The problem persists with no activated plugins, stock theme (twentysixteen) and reinstalled core files.

Tested for .htaccess related issue and mod_security. Also tried a few php versions (5.6, 7.0, 7.1). All suhosin limits were increased as well.

Server error logs and WP error logs are clean.

Anybody had a similar problem? Any ideas will be highly appreciated!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please check your database table wp_posts > post_content columan  type it should be longtext

Comment: Just checked it, the post_content column is set to longcontent.

Comment: Make it longtext and then check

Comment: Sorry for that, I've misspelled longtext with longcontent.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question to mark the solution that worked for me.

I have moved the site to a different hosting company. All works as expected with no changes made to the site.

Still unaware where the problem was. According the the old host, it's a WordPress issue. Yet again, new host -> functioning site.